# Change root file aws nginx server

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, symfony-2.8

I have been stucked with this for a while. We have a Symfony 2.8 project and I want to deploy it to the cloud. I have properly created the ElasticBeanstalk environment and it works! But I still need to access http://domain/app.php in order to make it work. I managed to delete web/ changing documentDirectory part from URL but app.php is still there.

I have also tried with a new brand project following this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-symfony-tutorial.html
But when I change it to public/ happens to me the same I need to use index.php in the URL

I have modified NGINX conf following:
https://community.bitnami.com/t/how-to-change-default-root/65639/9
https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

This is what I added to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.default

```
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php$is_args$args;
}

 location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
    fastcgi_index app.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

I have restart nginx service using

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

but it remains the same.

I have also tried renaming app.php to index.php just in case. But I need to add /index.php to the URL then.

Any idea?

Comment: What about adding `index app.php;` to the server block outside any locations?

Comment: I have tried what you said but is not working. How can I check If NGINX server is actually restarting and applitying modifications? I have tried so many things and is not even breaking it

Comment: I'm re-read your question, why do you apply your changes to `nginx.conf.default` instead of `nginx.conf`? Run `nginx -V` and look for `--conf-path=<filename>` parameter, it is the config file that nginx is using.

Comment: Also do not forget to run `nginx -t` to test your new configuration for errors before restarting/reloading nginx.

Comment: It worked editing nginx.conf instead of nginx.conf.default! Thanks But I still have an issue: / does not work. I mean root URL is not working if I don't use app.php/. The rest is working. Why is this happening? It gives me 403 forbbiden

Comment: Even with the `index app.php;` directive?

Comment: That made the trick I forgot to migrate that configuration. I just need to prepare some elasticbeanstalk configuration so I don't lose this when I deploy the app. Thanks a lot!! Can you write this as an answer so I can check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `index` nginx directive to make `app.php` the default handler of `http://domain/` requests:

```
server {
    ...
    index    app.php;
    # your locations here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fast replys. I would remark the nginx -V to see what file is using and edit it properly

Comment: This command is also useful when you need to check what modules are built with the nginx executable.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things you can try.

https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx

Here you can find a configuration for your project. There you can see that the location is rewritten to the `app.php`.

```
location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
```

so i would suggest to take the configuration and test it.

Comment: I have tried but nothing. I'm starting to think that NGINX is not restarting and appliying new config. I'll work arround that. Thanks for response!

Comment: When nginx is not restartung then try "systemctl status nginx" then you should see the error or look in the logs.

Comment: It seems that it restarted:

Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
 Started The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
but it seems that is ignoring changes. Should I edit a different file?